# Pandas: Grouping cell values by value into individual columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame with multiple offset columns:

```
        0       1       2       3        4         5          6
0  532201  577834  577837  839786  1003273       NaN        NaN
1  577834  577837  649835  839786  1003273       NaN        NaN
2  577834  577837  649835  839786  1003273       NaN        NaN
3  577834  577837  649839  649845   839785  839786.0  1003273.0
4  577834  577837  649839  839786  1003273       NaN        NaN
5  577834  577837  649839  839786  1003273       NaN        NaN
6  577834  577837  649839  839786  1003273       NaN        NaN
```

Is it possible to efficiently group/sort the columns by the values of the cells while inserting NaN, -1, or some other value in the missing locations?

Output:

```
        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7        8
0  532201  577834  577837     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  839786  1003273
1     NaN  577834  577837  649835     NaN     NaN     NaN  839786  1003273
2     NaN  577834  577837  649835     NaN     NaN     NaN  839786  1003273
3     NaN  577834  577837     NaN  649839  649845  839785  839786  1003273
4     NaN  577834  577837     NaN  649839     NaN     NaN  839786  1003273
5     NaN  577834  577837     NaN  649839     NaN     NaN  839786  1003273
6     NaN  577834  577837     NaN  649839     NaN     NaN  839786  1003273
```

The columns don't need to be sorted in any particular manner, I'm just looking to create timeline plots for each of the above values.

e.g.

```
.
.
.
649839       ======== 
577837  ================================
577834  ================================
532201  ===
         0    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

Comment: If you have the unique sorted list of all elements in your dataframe, you can basically iterate through it while checking if each value exists in a row or not. If yes, then return the value else return nan. that way each row is now fixed length and covers complete timeline. Check my solution for how that would work.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with dummies. `stack`, create dummies and use `max` to create indicators of existence anywhere across the row.

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.stack().astype('int64')).max(level=0)

   532201   577834   577837   649835   649839   649845   839785   839786   1003273
0        1        1        1        0        0        0        0        1        1
1        0        1        1        1        0        0        0        1        1
2        0        1        1        1        0        0        0        1        1
3        0        1        1        0        1        1        1        1        1
4        0        1        1        0        1        0        0        1        1
5        0        1        1        0        1        0        0        1        1
6        0        1        1        0        1        0        0        1        1
```

---

If you want to create something like that plot, we can multiply the dummies by a  different constant for each column (so they are offset when plotting), replacing the 0s with `NaN`, and plot against the RangeIndex of the DataFrame. You can use a legend to label the lines, or play around with the yticks and labels, so the column labels are on the y-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

(df1.mul(np.arange(1, df1.shape[1]+1)).replace(0, np.NaN)
    .plot(ax=ax, marker='o', legend=False))

plt.yticks(np.arange(1, df1.shape[1]+1, 1))
ax.set_yticklabels(df1.columns)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Well that works perfectly.  Now I just need to figure out how to make those timelines.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ErstBlack I added one way to get close to something you want, albeit a bit ugly :D with the defaults.

Comment: Well that looks one hell of a lot better than what I was doing with some imshow nonsense.  The replacement part in particular to space them nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Comments inline to explain how it works -

```
#Get sorted array of all unique values in the dataset except nans
unique_vals = df.stack().dropna().sort_values().unique()

#Iterate all unique values in order and return nan if they are not in row
f = lambda row: pd.Series([i if i in list(row) else None for i in unique_vals])

#Apply lambda function to each row
out = df.apply(f, axis=1)
out
```

[image]

---

**NOTE:** If you don't need any sorted order for columns, you can remove the `.sort_values()` from the first line of code to improve runtime.